# A compact hyperbolic manifold and fundmental group

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, fundamental-groups

I just start to learn differential geometry and have a problem. Let $M$ be a compact hyperbolic manifold, how to prove **Z** $\oplus$ **Z** is not a subgroup of $\pi_1(M)$ .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: If you were really Chern, you wouldn't have these difficulties. :D Signed, a Chern student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to prove this is to use [Preissman's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preissman%27s_theorem), 
which says that if $M$ is a compact negatively curved Riemannian manifold, then every non-trivial abelian subgroup of $\pi_1(M)$ must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. In particular, if $M$ is a compact hyperbolic manifold, then $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$, 
which is abelian and is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, cannot be a subgroup of $\pi_1(M)$.

But using Preissman's Theorem may be overkill: if $M$ is a hyperbolic manifold, i.e. has constant negative sectional curvature, there may be some simpler way to prove it.